# Count two different timestamps into datetime buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by

My PostgreSQL dataset has an entry per task, including a 'task_id' as well as a 'created' and a 'completed' timestamp. Now I want to generate a series of 20 min time slots and for each time slot show the number of tasks that were created and completed. 
Desired result:

[image]

However, I can't seem to figure out how to group the task_id for two different time stamps per row in an efficient way, without too many subqueries.

I am able to create the 20 minute time slots and group the created vs completed cases separately, then joining everything together via the time slot column. The code below shows the example for the case of 'completed' cases.

```
SELECT grid.t20,count(distinct id) as completed
FROM (
   SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('hour',min(task_creation_date))::timestamp
                         ,date_trunc('hour',max(task_creation_date))::timestamp, interval '20 min') AS t20
   FROM task
   ) grid
LEFT JOIN task t ON t.task_creation_date >= grid.t20
               AND t.task_creation_date <  grid.t20 +  interval '20 min'

where task_creation_date > now() - interval '6 month'
GROUP  BY grid.t20
ORDER  BY grid.t20
```

Comment: What is your problem. Your query looks good. Just join completes...

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way instead of doing the same query for creations and then joining

Comment: I would do it in a very similar way, but maybe another one has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't quite right:

```
SELECT grid.t20,count(distinct id) as completed
FROM (SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('hour', min(task_creation_date))::timestamp,
                             date_trunc('hour', max(task_creation_date))::timestamp,
                             interval '20 min'
                            ) AS t20
      FROM task
      WHERE task_creation_date > now() - interval '6 month'
     ) grid LEFT JOIN
     task t
     ON t.task_creation_date >= grid.t20 AND
        t.task_creation_date <  grid.t20 +  interval '20 min'
GROUP  BY grid.t20
ORDER  BY grid.t20;
```

The filtering on the date needs to be reflected in the generation of `grid`.  Otherwise, it turns the outer join into an inner join.